# Generate all possible permutations of a binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix, permutation

I'm looking to generate all possible 4x4 matrices, where each element can either be a 0 or a 1.

Is there a function in R to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function that would create such matrices for indices from `0` to `2^16-1`:

```
num2mat = function(num){ matrix(as.integer(intToBits(num)),4,4) }
```

Here is what it produces:

```
> num2mat(0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

> num2mat(2^15+2^13+2^10+2^8+2^7+2^5+2^2+1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1

> num2mat(2^16-1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
```